# Q3DSurface - define a simple Graph

Tags: qt

I am really new to Qt-coding (and coding in general) and would like to plot a numeric function. I thought the best tool/class to use would be `Q3DSurface`. 
Unfortunately I can not even define a simple graph. I tried to use that example 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html
but I am not even able to write the following line from the `main.cpp`

`Q3DSurface *graph = new Q3DSurface();`

Obviously there is no constructor without arguments in the version 5.9.
This is my attempt so far:

```
using namespace QtDataVisualization;

Surface::Surface()
{
    QSurfaceFormat* format= new QSurfaceFormat();
    QWindow * window= new QWindow(Q_NULLPTR);
    Q3DSurface* m_pGraph= new Q3DSurface(format, window); 
}
```

The constructor is defined as

```
Q3DSurface(const QSurfaceFormat *format = Q_NULLPTR, QWindow *parent = Q_NULLPTR).
```

This attempt isn't working. Do you have an idea how I could create a new object of Q3DSurface?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I just would like to know,how i could define that m_pGraph. My attempt isn't working. I don't now how to write the constructor for it. How would you create an Object of Q3DSurface?